# Int Value is not changing in button.SetOnClickListener()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the value of circuitLength when `fiveMinuteButton` is **clicked**, however, the value is not being changed.

```
 private Button fiveMinuteButton;
 int circuitLength;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_settings_screen);

    fiveMinuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fiveminutesbuttonid);



    fiveMinuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            circuitLength = 5;

        }
    });
```

**XML:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/fiveminutesbuttonid"
    android:background="@drawable/whitebutton_shape"
    android:layout_below="@+id/workoutlengthtitleId"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/fiveminutes_text"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

Comment: show `InitialzeUIButtons()` and xml layout?

Comment: I just changed it, I'm really not sure why the value isn't being stored into the circuitLength

Comment: add toast in on click then check the value for testing.

Comment: Put a log like Log.d(TAG, "value is:" + circuitLength);. If this one shows 5, meaning the click listener did its job then we can discuss other scenarios.

Comment: I put a log. It only stores the value temporarily, then after I call log again outside of the OnClickListener, the value is null.

Comment: how did you know that the value is not changing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code then let me know the out then we further investigate.

```
 private Button fiveMinuteButton;
 int circuitLength;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_settings_screen);


    Toast.makeText(this,"circuitLength value ="+circuitLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    fiveMinuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fiveminutesbuttonid);
    fiveMinuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            circuitLength = 5;
            Toast.makeText(ACtivityName.this,"circuitLength value ="+circuitLength, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, I ended up updating Android Studio's latest version and restarting it. Then, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not be updated as you are `initializing` value 5 every time when you click on `fiveMinuteButton` (i.e. circuitLength = 5 instead write circuitLength = circuitLength + 5).

Change your code to following.

```
private Button fiveMinuteButton;
 int circuitLength;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_settings_screen);
    fiveMinuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fiveminutesbuttonid);
    circuitLength = 5;
    InitialzeUIButtons();



    fiveMinuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            circuitLength = circuitLength + 5;

        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't want to increment it +=5. I want 5 to be stored in circuitLength even if it's clicked 1000 times.

Comment: Show the code you've written in InitialzeUIButtons().

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct make sure onclick the button call or not 
i think, your onclick button is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct for sure. if you change any variable inside Activity it remains changed, there are three possibility it changes to initial value.

1. Activity stopped.
2. Activity Recreated.
3. variable changed manually.

as you said here

> I put a log. It only stores the value temporarily, then after I call
>   log again outside of the OnClickListener, the value is null.

I believe you are doing something like this.

```
private Button fiveMinuteButton;
int circuitLength;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_workout_settings_screen);

    fiveMinuteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fiveminutesbuttonid);

    fiveMinuteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            circuitLength = 5;

            Log.e("count", ""+circuitLength);
        }
    });
    Log.e("count", ""+circuitLength);
}
```

Now when you app starts `onCreate` will called by default `circuitLength` is null so it is obvious you are getting null in log.

I hope it is clear. if you have any query feel free to ask.